# C++, why am I getting access violations after modifying newly allocated objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Alright, so I'm currently working on a game and ran into a memory issue after refactoring some of the code today.

It uses a component based design and I was modifying how the components were allocated and passed off to entities. Originally some components were allocated as member variables within the entities but now I want to have them allocated elsewhere and passed off to the entity via pointer.

You can see how I implemented this below with sample code from my project. I essentially iterate through all the entities and allocate the components for them. The problem is I'm hitting a access violation at the first line of "starting up" the "instanceObject" on the 6th iteration and have no idea why. Using the debugger, it doesn't look like any of the variables point to a invalid address.

Here is what I'm doing to create the entities and components.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 512; ++i) {
    InstanceObject* _pInstanceObject = new InstanceObject;

    // Initialize temporary variables
    XMFLOAT3 _position, _rotation;
    float _angle = (i / 512.0f) * (2.0f * XM_PI),
          _scale = (float)pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(50, 5);

    _position.x = 100000.0f * cos(_angle) + pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(50000, -25000);
    _position.y =(float) pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(50000, -25000);
    _position.z = 100000.0f * sin(_angle) + pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(50000, -25000);

    _rotation.x = (XM_PI * 2) * (pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(100, 0) / 100.0f);
    _rotation.y = (XM_PI * 2) * (pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(100, 0) / 100.0f);
    _rotation.z = (XM_PI * 2) * (pResourceManager->numberGenerator.GetInt(100, 0) / 100.0f);

    // Set component's state using the temporary variables.
    _pInstanceObject->StartUp(&_position,
        &_rotation,
        &XMFLOAT3(_scale, _scale, _scale),
        &XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        &XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        &XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        );

    // Hand pointer of the component to entity.
    // Entity will handle deallocating component
}
```

And here is the relevant code from the component.

```
class InstanceObject {
private:
    XMVECTOR anteriorAxis,
         lateralAxis,
         normalAxis,
         position,
         rotationQuaternion,
         scale;

    XMMATRIX translationMatrix,
         rotationMatrix,
         scaleMatrix;
    void SetAnteriorAxis(const XMFLOAT3 *_anteriorAxis) { anteriorAxis = XMLoadFloat3(_anteriorAxis); }
    void SetLateralAxis(const XMFLOAT3 *_lateralAxis)   { lateralAxis = XMLoadFloat3(_lateralAxis); }
    void SetNormalAxis(const XMFLOAT3 *_normalAxis)     { normalAxis = XMLoadFloat3(_normalAxis); }
public:
    InstanceObject(void)  { }
    InstanceObject(const InstanceObject& _object) : anteriorAxis(_object.anteriorAxis), lateralAxis(_object.lateralAxis),
        normalAxis(_object.normalAxis), position(_object.position), rotationQuaternion(_object.rotationQuaternion), scale(_object.scale),
        translationMatrix(_object.translationMatrix), rotationMatrix(_object.rotationMatrix), scaleMatrix(_object.scaleMatrix) {}
    ~InstanceObject(void) { }

    bool StartUp(const XMFLOAT3 *_position, const XMFLOAT3 *_rotation, const XMFLOAT3 *_scale,
        const XMFLOAT3 *_lookAxis, const XMFLOAT3 *_strafeAxis, const XMFLOAT3 *_upAxis);

    void SetPosition(const XMFLOAT3* _position) { position = XMLoadFloat3(_position); }
    void SetRotationQuaternion(const XMFLOAT3 *_rotation) { rotationQuaternion = XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw(_rotation->x, _rotation->y, _rotation->z); }
    void SetScale(const XMFLOAT3 *_scale) { scale = XMLoadFloat3(_scale); }
}

bool InstanceObject::StartUp(const XMFLOAT3 *_position, const  XMFLOAT3 *_rotation, const XMFLOAT3 *_scale,
        const XMFLOAT3 *_lookAxis, const XMFLOAT3 *_strafeAxis, const XMFLOAT3 *_upAxis) {
    SetPosition(_position);
    SetRotationQuaternion(_rotation);
    SetScale(_scale);   
    SetAnteriorAxis(_lookAxis);
    SetLateralAxis(_strafeAxis);
    SetNormalAxis(_upAxis);

    return true;
}
```

Any idea of what could be causing this behavior and how should I fix it?

Comment: There's one thing that's not in the code that could definitely cause problems, the constructor of XMLoadFloat3 (or is it a function?) that takes a XMFLOAT3* (it doesn't store that pointer, does it?)

Comment: The copy constructor of `InstanceObject` is just like the one that would be generated for free by the compiler. You could just delete it and you would get the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't see why it would. It loads an array of 3 floats into a XMVECTOR which is a special datatype that uses a SIMD register or something. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.loading.xmloadfloat3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and explicitly declared the copy constructor just so I could rule that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the XMVECTOR in your InstanceObject class need to be 16 byte aligned, and the new operator won't guarantee this for you. You can add a quick check into your code to confirm - check whether the InstanceObject pointer & 0xF is non zero in the iteration in which it crashes.

If that is the case you can write a custom allocator that guarantees the right alignment and use placement new.

It seems to be a fairly common problem with XMVECTOR when used as a member (here's an existing [Connect bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499164/xmvector-m128-as-a-class-ember-access-violation) on this issue, there are a few web pages if you search).

If you just want to fix it quickly to let you get on with other things, you can add a static operator new and delete to your class declaration implemented something like the following snippet:

```
void* InstanceObject::operator new( size_t size )
{
    // _aligned_malloc is a Microsoft specific method (include malloc.h) but its
    // straightforward to implement if you want to be portable by over-allocating
    // and adjusting the address
    void *result = _aligned_malloc( size, 16 );
    if( result )
        return result;

    throw std::bad_alloc(); 
}

void InstanceObject::operator delete( void* p )
{
    if( p ) _aligned_free(p);
}
```

If the `InstanceObject` share a common lifetime you could replace the use of _aligned_malloc with your own aligned arena allocator and make the `delete` a no-op to improve efficiency.

Comment: `new` is supposed to return memory properly aligned for the object, but maybe the compiler doesn't treat the SSE types properly in respect to this. It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: So far your answer appears to be correct. The "bad" iteration isn't getting a 16 byte aligned pointer. Going to take a break from staring at this all day and then I'll test out a custom allocator. Could I just declare the member XMVECTOR variables with the __declspec(align(16)) macro? I've never needed or written a custom allocator before.

Answer (score 4):

You're taking the addresses of temporaries! That's not even allowed!

```
// Set component's state using the temporary variables.
_pInstanceObject->StartUp(&_position,
    &_rotation,
    &XMFLOAT3(_scale, _scale, _scale), // not valid
    &XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // not valid
    &XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // not valid
    &XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) // not valid
    );
```

I suggest that you turn up the warning levels on your compiler settings, and enable as much standard conformance as possible. Things get much easier when **your compiler** tells you what you're doing wrong.

As a solution, you could try simply passing the objects by value:

```
_pInstanceObject->StartUp(_position,
    _rotation,
    XMFLOAT3(_scale, _scale, _scale),
    XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
    );


bool StartUp(XMFLOAT3 _position, XMFLOAT3 _rotation, XMFLOAT3 _scale,
    XMFLOAT3 _lookAxis, XMFLOAT3 _strafeAxis, XMFLOAT3 _upAxis);
```

Comment: Wouldn't passing by `XMFLOAT3 const &` be more efficient?

Comment: @AzzA: maybe, maybe not. Note that the function is going to store it in the class. I don't dare predict how an undisclosed compiler will optimize this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue. I've always used this approach in loading XMVECTORs. As long as the XMFLOAT3 is intact on the stack when it gets loaded it is fine. That being said I try passing by value with no luck.

Comment: Only Visual Studio will accept such code, I believe, and it's perfectly safe as long as the pointers aren't kept around- just the same as references.

Comment: You mean, if there are move constructors defined, it would be more efficient to pass temporaries by value?

Comment: @KlashnikovKid By the way, in VS2010 you'll get `warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue`. Your assumption is that compiler will preserve temporaries for the duration of the function call. If temporaries passed by `const &` that is the case. But when you take address of a temporary, I don't think compiler is bound to keep them. I think, it might as well just create all temporaries in turn in the same place on stack.

Comment: @AzzA: I don't know what would be more efficient.

Comment: Well, I just checked it and VS2010, despite the warning, does allocate temporaries passed by address at different address. So it's not the issue here, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XMFLOAT3 structures are being allocated on the stack, not on the heap. They would get cleaned up when their variables go out of scope.

Try allocating your structures on the heap instead:

```
XMFLOAT3* _position = new XMFLOAT3;
```

Comment: I don't think this will make a difference. The XMFLOAT3s are immediately getting loaded into XMVECTORs. Unless there is a functional side effect I'm not aware of with loading XMFLOATs.